# Can you build Winforms applications with C++?

Tags: c++, winforms

I saw some Youtube videos that claimed they showed how to build a C++ applications using Winforms.

As far as I knew you needed something else like QT.  Is it really possible to build using the same WinForms you would use to build a C# application but with C++ instead?

Comment: You use C++/CLI, a language that is C++ compatible but requires different syntax for managed .NET classes.  Like those used by Winforms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WinForms is managed code and is usable from practically every language with runs on the CLR.  So standard native C++ can't build a winforms app.  However managed C++ or C++/CLI can build WinForm apps in native code.

In general though I would question why you were doing this.  If you are willing to have mixed mode C++ it would probably be much faster to

- Build the UI in C#
- Communicate with your native backend through a mixed mode C++ layer.

Comment: It is the best approach indead

Answer (score 2):

In VS ('05), you can go to `File->New->Project`... Then `Visual C++ -> CLR -> Windows Forms Application`. Have fun :)

Comment: Of course noting that the language then used is _not_ C++, but C++/CLI.

Comment: Yes, but not noted in _your_ answer, which makes your answer misleading, or at the least incomplete. ;-]

Comment: Fair enough. :-] But while that's true, I only mentioned because "CLR" means nothing to most people who can't tell C++ from Java from C#, which is __many people__. :-P

Comment: Haha, yeah (I deleted my comment). I should have mentioned it tho, but thanks for adding it as a comment.